# Asymptotic behaviour of $\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n+\frac{6}{5}+i\frac{2}{7})}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, special-functions

Find the asymptotic behaviour of

$$\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n+\frac{6}{5}+i\frac{2}{7})}\ \ \ (n\rightarrow \infty)$$

I know we must use Stirling's formula. But I can't .Thank you

Comment: Wolfram says it's $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Stirling formula, we have
$$\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n+a)}\sim e^{-a\ln n}\left[1+O(n^{-1})\right].$$
as $n\rightarrow \infty$. If $a=\frac65+\frac{2i}{7}$ (and, more generally, if $\Re a>0$), the limit is clearly $0$.

Comment: Then, is the asymptotic behaviour equal to $1/n^a$?

Comment: @Mark Yes, but it is better to write it as $e^{-a\ln n}$ to specify the branch of complex power.